# Database error inMYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

Is there a way I can use the Course_Module table to JOIN tables but ignore it when it comes to displaying results?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue, if I understand it correctly, is that there are multiple modules for a course.

So, the `Course_Module` table has two rows with the same `CourseID`, so your final output includes both of those rows.

This is correct behavior. If you ONLY want the course IDs (not `SELECT *`), try Kolink's `GROUP BY cm.CourseID`. I believe standard SQL requires an aggregation query to do a grouping, so try `SELECT cm.CourseID, COUNT(m.Module) FROM ... GROUP BY cm.CouseID`.

You could also just `SELECT DISTINCT cm.CourseID` to have the server eliminate the duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
GROUP BY `cm`.`CourseId`
```

Not sure how well it'd work, it might not even work at all if you're running in Strict Mode, but it's worth a try.